# What is the pdf from this probablity and statistics exam question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

A is an average student who has a probability of $1/3$ to pass any exam he gives. He needs to pass $4$ more to finish his studies. Let $X$ be the number of exams he will finally give until he finishes his studies. What is the expected number of exams he will give $ E[X] $?

Obviously, this means I will have to find the PDF and use $ E(x) = \sum_{x=4}^{\infty} \left[xf(x)\right] $. What my intuition says is that
$f(x) = \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^4 \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{x-4} $.
Since he will have to give at least $4$ exams to finish his studies and $(x-4)$ other exams that he didn't pass. But what I found is that
$ \sum_{x\in S} f(x) \neq 1 $
, which it should be. I'm missing something and I don't know what. Can someone please clear this out for me? Thanks

Comment: You can do math formatting with [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I'm currently working on it, it's my first question here, sorry :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We define a *successful trial* as *failing an exam*, and a *failed trial* as *passing an exam*, so that Wiki's formula for the mean of a negative binomial distribution can be applied.

After each exam (each Bernoulli trial), the student will continue to take exam(s) with probability $2/3$ (success parameter $2/3$), and this will stop upon his graduation with $4$ passed exams ($4$ failed Bernoulli trials).  The Negative Binomial distribution models the number of failed exams (successful trials), so $X - 4 \sim NB(4,2/3)$.

$$E[X] = \frac{\frac23 \cdot 4}{1 - \frac23} + 4 = 8 + 4 = 12$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer! Do you know where my mistake is? This is really what is bothering me and I've lost a bunch of time over it.

Comment: @Gspoon You've forgotten to count the different possible occurrences of failed and successful trials.  You have $x$ trials, out of which $k = x-4$ are successful trials, and $r = 4$.  The last trial must be a failed trial, so you have to left multiply it by a factor of $\binom{k+r-1}{k} = \binom{x-1}{3}$.

Comment: Oh you are right! This means that $ f(x) = {x-1 \choose 3} \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^{x-4} $ ?

Comment: Just tried to sum *this* $ f(x) $ and it checks out! It turns out to be = 1. Thank you very much, I've accepted your comment as answer.

Comment: Thanks for your accept.